# How to set node_auto_indexing to 'true' in Neo4j Virtual machine on azure?

Tags: javascript, azure, indexing, neo4j

How can I set node_auto_indexing to 'true' in Neo4j virtual machine created on windows azure?

[image: indexing]

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html) ?

Comment: Yes.I want to set it true from windows azure platform.

Comment: don't know about the azure image. Normally you would change the setting in `conf/neo4j.properties`.

Comment: Yes, as Stefan pointed out you need to change that in the config files.

Comment: But where can I find out config files in azure?